# Use column from one subquery in another subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm working with an entity attribute value model that has about 20 tables. I'm working on a query that has several subqueries. I'm attempting to find a way to make a column from one subquery available for use in a CASE statement in another subquery. Below is 1) the desired CASE statement; and 2) a working version of my query that does not include the desired CASE statement. I'm relatively new to SQL, and I've done some reading to suggest a CTE might be the right solution. If it is, the implementation isn't quite clear to me.

**Desired CASE statement**
Beginning at line 58 in the below query where there's a comment "get sum of premium and taxable fees per invoice"

```
JOIN ( -- get sum of premium and taxable fees per invoice
    SELECT
        pcf1.field_value,
        policy_modification_locator,
        policy_locator,
        invoice_locator, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'premium' THEN amount END) AS GrossPremium,
        SUM(CASE 
                WHEN (pcf1.field_value = 'FL' OR pcf1.field_value = 'TX' OR pcf1.field_value = 'LA' OR pcf1.field_value = 'MS' OR pcf1.field_value = 'AL' OR pcf1.field_value = 'GA' OR pcf1.field_value = 'SC' OR pcf1.field_value = 'NC' OR pcf1.field_value = 'VA' OR pcf1.field_value = 'DE') AND (fee_name = 'inspection_fee' OR fee_name = 'broker_fee') THEN amount
                WHEN (pcf1.field_value = 'MD' OR pcf1.field_value = 'NY') AND (fee_name = 'inspection_fee') THEN amount
                ELSE 0
            END) AS TaxableFees,
        SUM(CASE 
                WHEN (pcf1.field_value = 'MD' OR pcf1.field_value = 'NY') AND (fee_name = 'broker_fee') THEN amount 
                WHEN (pcf1.field_value = 'CT' OR pcf1.field_value = 'RI' OR pcf1.field_value = 'MA' OR pcf1.field_value = 'NJ' ) AND (fee_name = 'inspection_fee' OR fee_name = 'broker_fee') THEN amount 
                ELSE 0
            END) AS NonTaxableFees
    FROM financial_transaction
    GROUP BY invoice_locator
    ) AS fin1 on fin1.policy_locator = pol.locator
```

**Working query without CASE statement**

```
SELECT
    fin1.invoice_locator AS InvoiceNumber,
    CONCAT(phf1.field_value,' ',phf2.field_value) AS InsuredName,
    pol.locator AS PolicyNumber,
    pcf1.field_value AS HomeState,
    TaxType,
    TransactionType,
    Coverage,
    GrossPremium,
    GrossPremium AS NonAdmittedPremium, -- Need to expand if we ever decide to offer an admitted product
    TaxableFees,
    NonTaxableFees,
    TaxAmt
FROM policy AS pol
JOIN ( -- join policy to policy characteristics, need the additional join because 1 policy can have many policy characteristics
    SELECT
        pc.locator,
        pc.policy_locator
    FROM policy_characteristics AS pc
    JOIN policy AS pol ON pol.locator =  pc.policy_locator
    GROUP BY pol.locator
    ) AS pc ON pc.policy_locator = pol.locator
JOIN ( -- join policy characteristics to policy characteristics fields (risk state)
    SELECT
        policy_characteristics_locator,
        field_value
    FROM policy_characteristics_fields
    WHERE field_name = 'risk_state'
    ) AS pcf1 ON pcf1.policy_characteristics_locator = pc.locator
JOIN ( -- join policy characteristics to policy characteristics fields (policy type)
    SELECT
        policy_characteristics_locator,
        field_value as Coverage
    FROM policy_characteristics_fields
    WHERE field_name = 'policy_type'
    ) AS pcf2 ON pcf2.policy_characteristics_locator = pc.locator
JOIN ( -- join policy to policyholder fields (first name)
    SELECT
        policyholder_locator,
        field_value
    FROM policyholder_fields
    WHERE field_name = 'first_name'
    ) AS phf1 on phf1.policyholder_locator = pol.policyholder_locator
JOIN ( -- join policy to policyholder fields (last name)
    SELECT
        policyholder_locator,
        field_value
    FROM policyholder_fields
    WHERE field_name = 'last_name'
    ) AS phf2 on phf2.policyholder_locator = pol.policyholder_locator
JOIN ( -- get sum of premium and taxable fees per invoice
    SELECT
        policy_modification_locator,
        policy_locator,
        invoice_locator, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'premium' THEN amount END) AS GrossPremium,
        SUM(CASE WHEN fee_name = 'inspection_fee' OR fee_name = 'broker_fee' THEN amount END) AS TaxableFees,  -- need a state dynamic solution
        SUM(CASE WHEN fee_name = 'TEST' THEN amount END) AS NonTaxableFees -- need a state dynamic solution, INSET LIST OF NON TAXABLE FEES HERE
    FROM financial_transaction
    GROUP BY invoice_locator
    ) AS fin1 on fin1.policy_locator = pol.locator
LEFT JOIN ( -- get sum of taxes by tax per invoice, left join to include $0 endorsements that would otherwise be dropped out here
    SELECT
        invoice_locator,
        fee_name AS TaxType,
        SUM(amount) AS TaxAmt
    FROM financial_transaction
    WHERE (fee_name = 'empa_surcharge' OR fee_name = 'fslso_service_fee' OR fee_name = 'surplus_lines_tax') -- need a state dynamic solution
    GROUP BY invoice_locator, fee_name
    ) AS fin2 ON fin2.invoice_locator = fin1.invoice_locator
JOIN invoice AS inv on inv.locator = fin1.invoice_locator -- join financial transactions to invoice
JOIN ( -- join financial transactions to policy modifications
    SELECT 
        pm.locator,
        pm.type AS TransactionType
    FROM policy_modification AS pm
    JOIN financial_transaction AS fin ON fin.policy_modification_locator = pm.locator
    GROUP BY fin.invoice_locator
    ) AS pm ON pm.locator = fin1.policy_modification_locator
```

**UPDATE: This is an updated version of the query using CTE** I'm still getting the error "Unknown column 'pcf1.field_value' in 'field list' in the fin1 CTE." So it seems like the CTEs aren't making fields available across expressions as expected. This query otherwise works as expected if I remove references to pcf1.field_value.

```
WITH pc AS ( -- need the additional join because 1 policy can have many policy characteristics
    SELECT
        pc.locator,
        pc.policy_locator
    FROM policy_characteristics AS pc
    JOIN policy AS pol ON pol.locator =  pc.policy_locator
    GROUP BY pol.locator
    ),
    
pcf1 AS ( -- policy characteristics fields (risk state)
    SELECT
        policy_characteristics_locator,
        field_value
    FROM policy_characteristics_fields
    WHERE field_name = 'risk_state'
    ),
    
pcf2 AS ( -- policy characteristics fields (policy type)
    SELECT
        policy_characteristics_locator,
        field_value
    FROM policy_characteristics_fields
    WHERE field_name = 'policy_type'
    ),
    
phf1 AS ( -- policyholder fields (first name)
    SELECT
        policyholder_locator,
        field_value
    FROM policyholder_fields
    WHERE field_name = 'first_name'
    ),
    
phf2 AS  ( -- policyholder fields (last name)
    SELECT
        policyholder_locator,
        field_value
    FROM policyholder_fields
    WHERE field_name = 'last_name'
    ),
    
fin1 AS ( -- get sum of premium and taxable fees per invoice
    SELECT
        pcf1.field_value,
        policy_modification_locator,
        policy_locator,
        invoice_locator, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'premium' THEN amount END) AS GrossPremium
        SUM(CASE 
                WHEN pcf1.field_value IN ('FL','TX','LA','MS','AL','GA','SC','NC','VA','DE') AND (fee_name = 'inspection_fee' OR fee_name = 'broker_fee') THEN amount
                WHEN pcf1.field_value IN ('MD','NY') AND (fee_name = 'inspection_fee') THEN amount
                ELSE 0
            END) AS TaxableFees,
        SUM(CASE 
                WHEN pcf1.field_value IN ('MD','NY') AND (fee_name = 'broker_fee') THEN amount 
                WHEN pcf1.field_value IN ('CT','RI','MA','NJ' ) AND (fee_name = 'inspection_fee' OR fee_name = 'broker_fee') THEN amount 
                ELSE 0
            END) AS NonTaxableFees
    FROM financial_transaction
    GROUP BY invoice_locator
    ),
    
fin2 AS ( -- get sum of taxes by tax per invoice, left join to include $0 endorsements that would otherwise be dropped out here
    SELECT
        invoice_locator,
        fee_name,
        SUM(amount) AS TaxAmt
    FROM financial_transaction
    WHERE (fee_name = 'empa_surcharge' OR fee_name = 'fslso_service_fee' OR fee_name = 'surplus_lines_tax') -- NEED A STATE DYNAMIC SOLUTION HERE
    GROUP BY invoice_locator, fee_name
    ),
    
pm AS (
    SELECT 
        pm.locator,
        pm.type AS TransactionType
    FROM policy_modification AS pm
    JOIN financial_transaction AS fin ON fin.policy_modification_locator = pm.locator
    GROUP BY fin.invoice_locator
    )

SELECT
    fin1.invoice_locator AS InvoiceNumber,
    CONCAT(phf1.field_value,' ',phf2.field_value) AS InsuredName,
    pol.locator AS PolicyNumber,
    pcf1.field_value AS HomeState,
    fin2.fee_name AS TaxType,
    TransactionType,
    pcf2.field_value AS Coverage,
    GrossPremium,
    GrossPremium AS NonAdmittedPremium, -- Need to expand if we ever decide to offer an admitted product
    TaxableFees,
    NonTaxableFees,
    TaxAmt

FROM policy AS pol
JOIN pc ON pc.policy_locator = pol.locator  -- join policy to policy_characteristics
JOIN pcf1 ON pcf1.policy_characteristics_locator = pc.locator -- join policy_characteristics to policy_characteristics_fields
JOIN pcf2 ON pcf2.policy_characteristics_locator = pc.locator -- join policy_characteristics to policy_characteristics_fields
JOIN phf1 on phf1.policyholder_locator = pol.policyholder_locator -- join policy to policyholder fields
JOIN phf2 on phf2.policyholder_locator = pol.policyholder_locator -- join policy to policyholder fields
JOIN fin1 on fin1.policy_locator = pol.locator -- join policy to financial_transactions
LEFT JOIN fin2 ON fin2.invoice_locator = fin1.invoice_locator -- join financial_transactions to financial_transactions
JOIN invoice AS inv on inv.locator = fin1.invoice_locator -- join invoice to financial_transactions
JOIN pm ON pm.locator = fin1.policy_modification_locator -- join financial_trans
```

Comment: Did you consider using "IN" instead of "-"?
Example: pcf1.field_value IN ('FL','TX','LA','MS','AL','GA','SC','NC','VA','DE')

Comment: That's a much less verbose way to write out the list of states--thanks. That still doesn't solve the "unknown column 'pcf.field_value' in 'field list' error I get, which I think it dues to the fact that pcf.field_value is defined in a seperate subquery.

Comment: If I follow this right, you are trying to insert query 1 into query 2? If that is the case, the sub-query you want has no way to determine pcf1. I would attempt that abstraction in the outer query or put pcf1 into a #temp table.
The approach to this query could be helped with CTE's for sure, in that you can alias a query and apply multiple different constraints to its output. I think you should look into that more, they basically are the same as subqueries but are easier to work with.

Comment: It looks like the `FROM` clause got missed off of your final select statement in your most recent edit

Comment: Good catch Ijust added those back in

Comment: In the `fin1` cte you're attempting to select `pcf1.field_value` but you haven't joined to `pcf1` within that cte, which is why you're getting the Unknown column error. You'll have to join `pcf1` to the `financial_transactions` table within `fin1` in order for it to work

Answer (score 0):

If you convert all of your subqueries to CTEs you're able to accomplish this and make your query more readable, is the join here from `pm` to `pcf1` correct?

```
with pc as (
-- join policy to policy characteristics, need the additional join because 1 policy can have many policy characteristics
    SELECT
        pc.locator,
        pc.policy_locator
    FROM policy_characteristics AS pc
    JOIN policy AS pol ON pol.locator =  pc.policy_locator
    GROUP BY pol.locator
),

pcf1 as ( -- join policy characteristics to policy characteristics fields (risk state)
    SELECT
        policy_characteristics_locator,
        field_value
    FROM policy_characteristics_fields
    WHERE field_name = 'risk_state'
),

pcf2 as ( -- join policy characteristics to policy characteristics fields (policy type)
    SELECT
        policy_characteristics_locator,
        field_value as Coverage
    FROM policy_characteristics_fields
    WHERE field_name = 'policy_type'
),

phf1 as ( -- join policy to policyholder fields (first name)
    SELECT
        policyholder_locator,
        field_value
    FROM policyholder_fields
    WHERE field_name = 'first_name'
),

phf2 as  ( -- join policy to policyholder fields (last name)
    SELECT
        policyholder_locator,
        field_value
    FROM policyholder_fields
    WHERE field_name = 'last_name'
),

fin1 as ( -- get sum of premium and taxable fees per invoice
    SELECT
        policy_modification_locator,
        policy_locator,
        invoice_locator, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'premium' THEN amount END) AS GrossPremium,
        SUM(CASE WHEN fee_name = 'inspection_fee' OR fee_name = 'broker_fee' THEN amount END) AS TaxableFees,  -- need a state dynamic solution
        SUM(CASE WHEN fee_name = 'TEST' THEN amount END) AS NonTaxableFees -- need a state dynamic solution, INSET LIST OF NON TAXABLE FEES HERE
    FROM financial_transaction
    GROUP BY invoice_locator
),

fin2 as ( -- get sum of taxes by tax per invoice, left join to include $0 endorsements that would otherwise be dropped out here
    SELECT
        invoice_locator,
        fee_name AS TaxType,
        SUM(amount) AS TaxAmt
    FROM financial_transaction
    WHERE (fee_name = 'empa_surcharge' OR fee_name = 'fslso_service_fee' OR fee_name = 'surplus_lines_tax') -- need a state dynamic solution
    GROUP BY invoice_locator, fee_name
),

pm as ( -- join financial transactions to policy modifications
    SELECT 
        pm.locator,
        pm.type AS TransactionType
        SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'premium' THEN amount END) AS GrossPremium,
        SUM(CASE 
                WHEN (pcf1.field_value = 'FL' OR pcf1.field_value = 'TX' OR pcf1.field_value = 'LA' OR pcf1.field_value = 'MS' OR pcf1.field_value = 'AL' OR pcf1.field_value = 'GA' OR pcf1.field_value = 'SC' OR pcf1.field_value = 'NC' OR pcf1.field_value = 'VA' OR pcf1.field_value = 'DE') AND (fee_name = 'inspection_fee' OR fee_name = 'broker_fee') THEN amount
                WHEN (pcf1.field_value = 'MD' OR pcf1.field_value = 'NY') AND (fee_name = 'inspection_fee') THEN amount
                ELSE 0
            END) AS TaxableFees,
        SUM(CASE 
                WHEN (pcf1.field_value = 'MD' OR pcf1.field_value = 'NY') AND (fee_name = 'broker_fee') THEN amount 
                WHEN (pcf1.field_value = 'CT' OR pcf1.field_value = 'RI' OR pcf1.field_value = 'MA' OR pcf1.field_value = 'NJ' ) AND (fee_name = 'inspection_fee' OR fee_name = 'broker_fee') THEN amount 
                ELSE 0
            END) AS NonTaxableFees
    FROM policy_modification AS pm
    JOIN financial_transaction AS fin ON fin.policy_modification_locator = pm.locator
    JOIN pcf1 ON pcf1.policy_characteristics_locator = pm.locator
    GROUP BY fin.invoice_locator
)

SELECT
    fin1.invoice_locator AS InvoiceNumber,
    CONCAT(phf1.field_value,' ',phf2.field_value) AS InsuredName,
    pol.locator AS PolicyNumber,
    pcf1.field_value AS HomeState,
    TaxType,
    TransactionType,
    Coverage,
    GrossPremium,
    GrossPremium AS NonAdmittedPremium, -- Need to expand if we ever decide to offer an admitted product
    TaxableFees,
    NonTaxableFees,
    TaxAmt
FROM policy AS pol
JOIN pc ON pc.policy_locator = pol.locator
JOIN pcf1 ON pcf1.policy_characteristics_locator = pc.locator
JOIN pcf2 ON pcf2.policy_characteristics_locator = pc.locator
JOIN phf1 on phf1.policyholder_locator = pol.policyholder_locator
JOIN phf2 on phf2.policyholder_locator = pol.policyholder_locator
JOIN fin1 on fin1.policy_locator = pol.locator
LEFT JOIN fin2 ON fin2.invoice_locator = fin1.invoice_locator
JOIN invoice AS inv on inv.locator = fin1.invoice_locator -- join financial transactions to invoice
JOIN pm ON pm.locator = fin1.policy_modification_locator
```

Comment: This is a big help. The join I had in mind is a bit different but doesn't impact the overall solution. When I implement this, I'm still getting the error "Unknown column pcf1.field_value in field list". So it seems like the CTE isn't having the desired effect--I can confirm though that the query otherwise works as expected.

Comment: Did your query run despite not including all the non aggregated columns? If so I suggest including `pcf1.field_value` in the `pm` cte and selecting `pm.field_value As HomeState`

Comment: Let me repost the current query, I think I was unclear in my initial post.